# How to disable splash screen Ionic 7

Tags: angular, splash-screen, ionic7

I want to completely disable splash screen in ionic project. I use ionic 7, and it is new project with tabs. Do You have any idea how to do it?

I tried many things like instaling @capacitor/splash-screen and set launchShowDuration: 0, i tried remove cordova splasScreen plugin, and so on and so on,but nothing help.